# allocation of incomplete type 'T' c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing a dynamic array in c++ using a raw pointer. I'm new to using templates. I decided to split the class into two .hpp and .cpp files also for the sake of practice. I'm getting the following compilation error in the source file when initializing the T array:

"Allocation of incomplete type 'T'"

Here is the header file:

```
template <class T>
class DynArray {

public:
    DynArray(); //default constructor
private:
    T * array; //internal array
    int memsize; //number of allocated memory slots
    int t_size; //number of occupied memory slots
};
```

Here is the source file:

```
template <>
DynArray<class T>::DynArray() {
    memsize = 2;
    t_size = 0;
    array = new T[memsize];

}
```

I'm not comfortable with what I'm doing here in the source file. I basically followed what my IDE (xcode) told me to do, but something feels wrong about creating a specialized template here. What is a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Move the constructor content to the header. Template type declarations in source files don't really "work well".

Comment: Everything is correct, except it needs to be moved to the header. Well, mostly correct. You also need to change `template  <> DynArray<class T>::DynArray()` to `template <class T> DynArray<T>::DynArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this as a start point [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Regarding the error *Allocation of incomplete type 'T'*.  Please look carefully at the code

```
template <>
DynArray<class T>::DynArray()
```

`template` there does not introduce type `T`. The type `class T` is introduced in the second line, it is mentioned first time there. As you may know `class T` without `template` is a forward declaration and is an incomplete type, its size is unknown and `new` can not allocate memory of unknown size. The proper template class member should be declared like this

```
template <class T>
DynArray<T>::DynArray()
```

It is correct syntactically, but not practically, read the article mentioned above.